scroll event not working because lenis.js
I use lenis.js for smooth scrolling which works well.
While creating landing pages When I click on the menu, I implemented it to go to each other section.
But, scroll event doesn't work because of lenis.js.(maybe)
If you know how to solve it, please answer me!!! 
I applied a smooth scrolling effect using lenis.js. But using lenis.js, scroll event causes error. When I click on the menu, I made it go to the appropriate section, but it's not working properly because of lenis.js. I'm not sure what other good options are available
I'm sorry for my lack of English
thank u
HTML:
<ul class="menu">
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:" rel="section01">menu1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:" rel="section02">menu2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="javascript:" rel="section03">menu3</a>
   </li>     
</ul>

$(".menu li a").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let targetContent = $(this).attr("rel");
  let offset = $("#" + targetContent).offset().top;

  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 1000);
});


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. Please add relevant frameworks using a CDN and remember to post the error too
